# Is okay for function name() and prototype.name to have the same name

Tags: javascript

Is okay for a global & prototype function name to have the same function name.

```
function doThis(){}
```

&

```
el.prototype.doThis = function (){}
```

Can these two be used together in the same script?

I tried it and they both worked correctly, but I need to know if it's safe to use them together.

Comment: Depends on what `el` refers to.

Comment: el isn't inbuilt, just doSomething()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. They are stored in different scopes

```
function doThis(){}
```

Is in your global script scrope. // doThis();

```
el.prototype.doThis = function (){}
```

Is only accessable with the specified object `el`  // el.doThis();

I would prefer to name them differently to avoid misunderstandings.

Comment: Actually they would do the samething, but some circumstances would require me not calling the prototype but the global instead. And since they do samething, I wanted to give them the same name.

Comment: Why not use only the global function since it does not require any object related properties?

Comment: @SaschaGeier You should not create global variables at all. They're error prone (too easy to collide with each other), they're memory consuming (the global namespace is never garbage collected), they're slow (the global namespace is huge), they break encapsulation (it's too easy to access/change the values with DevTools), they may shadow native JS/DOM properties (many of them are placed in the global namespace too).

Comment: @Teemu thats true, but that was no part of the question...